# ¿Como hacer un UPDATE correlacionado con condiciones en PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo 2 tablas:

- La tabla `Solicitudes`, con las columnas `Id_cliente` y `No_cuenta_prestamo`
- La tabla `Disposiciones`, con las columnas `Id_cliente` y `Estado_Actual`

Posterioremente corro el siguiente codigo:

```
ALTER TABLE solicitudes.
ADD respuesta varchar2(40) DEFAULT 'NO ES MODIFICACION'
```

Y le agrego una nueva columna a la tabla `Solicitudes` llamada `Repuesta` con un valor por defecto de texto que dice `"NO ES MODIFICACION"`

El valor de la columa `Respuesta` varía en función de si un mismo `Id_Cliente` tiene un `No_Cuenta_Prestamo` o no. Aparte de tener que tener un `No_Cuenta_Prestamo`, un registro tambien tiene que tener un `Estado_Actual` igual a 1,2,10 o 12.

Si cumple con todas esas condiciones, el registro de la columna `Respuesta` de la tabla `Solicitudes`, deberá cambiarse a `MODIFICACION`.

Este es el codigo que hasta el momento utilizo, basado en un update correlacionado:

```
ALTER TABLE solicitudes.
   ADD RESPUESTA varchar2(40) DEFAULT 'NO ES MODIFICACION'


UPDATE Solicitudes
SET r.respuesta = 'MODIFICACION'
WHERE d.No_Cuenta_Prestamo = NOT NULL
AND r.Estado_Actual = '1' OR '2' OR '10' OR '12'
FROM Solicitudes r, Disposiciones d
;
```

Obviamente PL SQL no no entinede que pasa, por que despues del `UPDATE` falla la expesion esperada.

Quiero buscar una alternativa a este metodo, ¿un left join?, ¿Un select espcial?, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Bienvenid@, Sobyro. Disculpa mi ignorancia, ya que no manejo PLSQL, pero en la sintaxis clásica de SQL, la forma en que has escrito tus condiciones hará muy probable que falle tu query. ¿Podrías mejor decirnos cuál es el error que te arroja? Ya que tanto en la condición `d.No_Cuenta_Prestamo`, generalmente debieras colocar `IS NOT NULL`, y no `= NOT NULL`; y en la siguiente, podrías usar el comparador `IN` en vez de esos `OR` (que como te digo, no sé si PLSQL aguanta ese tipo de sintaxis...).

Comment: No hay problema y gracias por los comentarios, desafortunadamete en este caso manda el error de que SQL no reconoce el FROM en donde se esperaba, mas que nada por que el Update no acepa FROM en ningun lugar.

Comment: Por favor, reescribe los dos últimos párrafos explicando qué problemas tienes y qué quieres, porque leyendo la pregunta final da la sensación de que quieres cambiar la forma de hacer algo en lugar de arreglar un código que no funciona

Comment: Uhm ahora que lo mencionas, no me había fijado en el lugar donde está el `FROM`... Pues los `UPDATE` sí soportan el `FROM`, pero para usarlo, generalmente debes emplear alias para las tablas. Algo como `UPDATE r SET ... FROM Solicitudes r, Disposiciones d;`. Como sea, en teoría sí puedes usar `JOIN`, recuerda aplicar los alias, como ya te ejemplifiqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que quieres hacer podrías hacerlo con un PL en el que abras un cursor y vayas haciendo las comprobaciones necesarias o con una subselect. Lo más rápido es una subselect. Sería algo así:

```
UPDATE Solicitudes
SET respuesta = 'MODIFICACION'
WHERE Estado_Actual IN ('1','2','10','12')
  AND  Id_cliente IN (SELECT Id_cliente
                        FROM Disposiciones 
                       WHERE No_Cuenta_Prestamo IS NOT NULL);
```